# How to correctly include javascript code in chameleon/zpt template (pyramid)?

Tags: javascript, python, pyramid, template-tal

I'm trying to embed some code between <**script**> <**/script**> tags, pyramid however doesn't like it and gives me

**ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)**

Probably because i have && in my code. I tried using `&amp;` instead, but then it didn't get interpreted in the browser.

The same thing happens when i try to put it in CDATA block.

When I move the code to a separate js file it works. I'd like to keep it in the same file for now, just to enable quick corrections.

So, how should I do it?

**EDIT:**

I get the same error even for templates as simple as this one:

```
<html
    xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
    xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span onclick="alert(true && false);">test</span>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like xhtml issue, as w3c validator reported the same error.

I was thinking if there's a switch to change the document type parsed by chameleon to html, but then it wouldn't be possible to include tal and metal namespaces.

Hence **it is expected behavior**

Answer (score 1):

I think you're supposed to put && (i.e. two times the HTML entity code).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        // my javascript
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: If it's commented out, it won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `type` attribute to your script tag?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the ampersands? `alert(true \&\& false);` I've experienced an issue like this with with curly brackets and Smarty

Comment: there should be some kind of a switch to turn off validation, but its really strange it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: That's annoying. =(  With Smarty, for instance, `{` is a reserved character in templates, and so on-page Style tags `body {font-size:12px;}` are just completely illegal and have to be externalized...~

Comment: and very off-putting, especially when just starting a project :/